# How to substitute sources for browser bundle with Rollup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, rollupjs

Using rollup is it possible to replace a specific source by another source in a NPM package during a browser bundle? Note this source is dynamically imported via `import('./relativeFile.js')` (I want this to be replaced).

I've specified `{ "browser": { "./relativeFile.js": "./browserFile.js" } }` in package.json of one of the node_modules to see how it goes, but Rollup still bundles `./relativeFile.js` instead. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`nodeResolve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve) and [`replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace) plugins to indicate it is a browser bundle. Rollup will then replace Node sources by Web Browser sources.

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

export default {
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      browser: true,
    }),
    replace({
      values:{
        'process.browser': true,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```